# Dropbox system tray icon old right-click menu

Tags: dropbox

Is it by design, that the old Dropbox system tray right-click menu is gone in version 2.4.2? 
Can this still be set somewhere instead of the pop-up menu showing the recent files, etc. that is now identical for left-click and right-click?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: I spoke too soon. You can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left-click</kbd> to get the old menu ;)

---

This is by design. I doubt you can get the old functionality back (without hacking the Dropbox-client).

BTW. The old menu is still there under the gear-icon in the Right-(or Left-)click menu.

[image: Dropbox]

Comment: @Wimbo **Edit**: I spoke too soon. You can do **Ctrl+Left-click** to get the old menu ;)